# Is there a reasoning to how often and long the notification light blinks?

Tags: notifications

I have a Droid X.  The green light on the front blinks when something has happened, but I've noticed that the number of blinks and their length is not consistent.

Is there some method to it?  Some code to it?  Does it reflect the event that has occurred in some way>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some apps will use the LED to indicate that there is a notification. For instance, the LED blinks green for me when I've received an e-mail message and blinks blue when Twitter has a message for me.

There's no consistency as to how to manage these, however. For instance Google Voice has it under `Menu | More | Settings | Sync and notifications | Light`, but no way to choose the color. Gmail doesn't offer any way to control it.